# ~/.bash_profile in OSX version 10.11.6 for virtualenv and Python

Tags: python, opencv, bash

So when I just write these commands in the terminal I get these errors:

```
 /  L/F/P  Versions  export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3                                                                    ➶ 127  04:21:45 PM
 /  L/F/P  Versions  source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh                                                                                        04:21:52 PM
Expected end of the statement, but instead found a '&'
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh (line 67): if [ "$OS" = "Windows_NT" ] && ([ "$MSYSTEM" = "MINGW32" ] || [ "$MSYSTEM" = "MINGW64" ])
                                                                            ^
from sourcing file /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file '/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
```

Also when I write them in `~/.bash_profile` I get these errors:

```
 /  L/F/P  Versions  vi ~/.bash_profile                                                                                                                04:18:50 PM
 /  L/F/P  Versions  source ~/.bash_profile                                                                                                            04:21:11 PM
Unsupported use of '&&'. In fish, please use 'COMMAND; and COMMAND'.
~/.bash_profile (line 3): [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
                                                     ^
from sourcing file ~/.bash_profile
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file '/Users/mona/.bash_profile'
```

I have these in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
 ~/.bash_profile
  1 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
  2
  3 [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
  4
  5 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  6
  7 # Setting PATH for Python 3.4
  8 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
  9 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
 10 export PATH
 11
 12 # added by Anaconda2 2.4.1 installer
 13 export PATH="/Users/mona/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
 14
 15 compresspdf() {
 16       gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/${3:-"screen"} -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sOutputFile=$2 $1
 17     }
 18
 19
 20 export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
 21 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 22 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
 23 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
~
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

```
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/
```

Thanks for any help or comment.

```
 /  L/F/P  Versions  python                                                                                                                            04:28:32 PM
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 28 2016, 21:28:07)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Your shell is not bash. The commands there are intended for use with `bash` shell. As a quick workaround, you should be able to launch bash simply by typing `bash`. Assuming it's installed.

Comment: I also found [this link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/) that seems to explain how to change your default shell.

Comment: I know that i can use `bash` command to move to bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `fish` shell. Your bash profile is written using items that are apparently unsupported by fish, see specifically

```
Unsupported use of '&&'. In fish, please use 'COMMAND; and COMMAND'.
```

From when you tried to source your bash profile. You may need to find a different tutorial to follow, create the virtualenvs yourself, or try to translate the bash pieces of the tutorial to fish.

Comment: can we make fish shell compatible with bash profile?